# nodejs binary streaming on socket disconnection produce extra size of data

Tags: node.js, sockets, streaming

I am trying to stream images over sockets from server to client and it works ok if no disconnect reconnect occurs But if I did disconnect reconnect in code I realized size increase.

here is the code sample

Server side

```
    socket.on('get file', function () {
    path = '../../../default/files/20141120_191129_0.jpg';
    fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        stream = fs.createReadStream(path,
                {encoding: 'binary'});

        stream.on('data', function (data) {
            socket.emit('file', {"data": data, "size" : stat.size})
        });
        console.log(stat.size);
    });

});
```

Client side
that piece of code works fine and logs shows less that 100% (upload progress)

console.log results `95.1968693802965 %
chat (line 201)
2065278
chat (line 208)
1966080
chat (line 209)
98.37009835963973 %
chat (line 201)
2065278
chat (line 208)
2031616
chat (line 209)
2065278`

```
       socket.on('connect', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            socket.emit('get file');
        }, 1000);
    });

    var base64string = '';
    var i =0;

    socket.on('file', function (data) {i++;
        console.log((base64string.length / data.size) * 100+" %");

        base64string += data.data;
        if(data.size == base64string.length){
          buildimage(base64string);  
        }
    })
    function buildimage(base64str) {
        console.log(base64str.length);
        $("#img").attr("src", 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(base64str));
    }
```

But if I changed the client side to disconnect reconnect It fails and the binary data size is bigger than the original image size

console.log results `142.79530407044476 %
chat (line 201)
2065278
chat (line 208)
2949120
chat (line 209)
145.96853304978796 %
chat (line 201)
2065278
chat (line 208)
3014656`

```
        socket.on('connect', function () {
        $('#chat').addClass('connected');
        setTimeout(function () {
            socket.emit('get file');
        }, 1000);
    });


    var base64string = '';
    var i =0;
    socket.on('file', function (data) {i++;
        console.log((base64string.length / data.size) * 100+" %");
    if (i == 15) {
      socket.disconnect();
      console.log('disconnected');
      socket.connect();
    }

    console.log(data.size);
        console.log(base64string.length);
        base64string += data.data;
        if(data.size == base64string.length){
          buildimage(base64string);  
        }

    })

    function buildimage(base64str) {
        console.log(base64str.length);
        $("#img").attr("src", 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(base64str));
    }
```

Why the variable size increased when disconnect reconnect happen which gives wrong progress tracking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when disconnect/reconnect happens the createreadstream starts reading the file from the beginning, So we have to set the start value based on the the length of variable storing the file on client side

Simple changes needed to make it work

Client side

```
            setTimeout(function () {
            // send the variable length as starting reading point
            socket.emit('get file', {start: base64string.length});
        }, 1000);
```

Server side

```
   socket.on('get file', function (options) {
    path = '../../../default/files/20141120_191129_0.jpg';

    fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
//take the starting reading point to start reading from
        stream = fs.createReadStream(path, {encoding: 'binary', start: options.start});
```